# Resources$NotFoundException report from wild

Tags: android, exception, resources

I just released an update and got an exception report from the wild after someone updated a previously working application.

The same code works on my phone, the resource is a raw file and not dependent on device, local dependent or anything.

I had a similar thing happen before while developing the update, I cleaned the project and it resolved it.

However this doesn't seem to be a good solution as I cannot verify the fix, don't want to just shove a version out in case it fixes the issue.

Any advice as to cause or resolution would be massively appreciated!

## Stack Trace below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.beltane.apppro.TickerService:  
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040005 at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2969) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125) at  
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858) at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:    
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040005 at 
android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892) at   
android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:854) at 
android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:647) at   
com.beltane.apppro.TickerService.onCreate(TickerService.java:42) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2959) ... 10 more
```

Comment: I think problem with xml file can you post xml file as well

Comment: It's a media player referencing a resource that is in the raw directory, there is no XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing a similar problem my resolution as horrible as it is:

Prepare a new release deleting all intermediate generated files, doing a clean build and re-releasing.

I trapped all media player creation code in try catch blocks for resource not found exceptions and pop up a toast explaining to the user what has occurred and to contact for a resolution.

This is pretty nasty but given that this should never occur...

I haven't heard either way from the user that returned the crash report, I have had other good feedback since, I'll update if I hear further either way.